# How can I set ipv6 autoconfig in Ubuntu 20.04 Server?

Tags: networking, server, 20.04, ipv6

How can I set ipv6 autoconfig in Ubuntu 20.04 Server, using Network Manager as render.

I want to create a script, that set different network configurations. I checked some material over the internet, but I'm not  sure how to do it.

Also if is disabled how to enabled back again.

Comment: It is enabled by default. What is the problem?

Comment: @guiverc - Ubuntu 20.04 server